# Objective C object not recognized in C function

Tags: objective-c, c, ios4, audiosessionservices

I am adding an Audio session property listener for kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange and in the callback I want to call the takePicture function of UIImagePickerController. The problem is that I cannot access my picker in the callback.

I am initializing my picker in viewDidLoad. I have tried declaring the picker as both a private and public object and accessing with picker or self.picker but it always gives the "Use of undeclared identifier" error. I use this code to add the listener:

```
AudioSessionInitialize(nil, nil, nil, nil);
AudioSessionSetActive(true);
AudioSessionAddPropertyListener(
                                kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange,
                                applicationAudioRouteDidChange,
                                self);
```

This is my callback:

```
void applicationVolumeDidChange(void *inClientData,
                                AudioSessionPropertyID inID,
                                UInt32 inDataSize, const void *inData)
{
    NSLog(@"Volume changed");
    //[picker takePicture]; Error

}
```

I also declared an NSArray to see if this was the problem with UIImagePickerController only but the array also gives the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last parameter of `AudioSessionAddPropertyListener()` is there so you can pass whatever you like into the callback.

```
 OSStatus AudioSessionAddPropertyListener (
       AudioSessionPropertyID         inID,
       AudioSessionPropertyListener   inProc,
       void                           *inClientData
    );
```

You are passing **self** so within the callback the `void *inClientData` parameter is a pointer to whichever object **self** is.

If self was an instance of UIImagePickerController then,

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = inClientData;
[picker takePicture];
```

Comment: self is my view controller so in my case i use `UIImagePickerController *myPicker = (RootViewController*)inClientData.picker;` Your direction was correct though.

Answer (score 1):

Your callbacks must be C functions, not Objective-C methods. These are not compatible. See [this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/AudioSessionServicesReference/Reference/reference.html).

Comment: my callback is a c function, im trying to access an objective c object from that function. Please read carefully before answering

Comment: Hmmm... I was sure I saw a method there. Sorry. So in effect, you have a scope problem. What is the "self" you are passing?

Comment: problem solved....have a look at the accepted answer. 'self' is a viewcontroller class

Comment: I will, thanks. Sorry again, don't know why I saw a method there. Glad it was solved.